# Can't compile code. Keep saying Error on bracket

Tags: c

```
bool Increase(void)
{
    num = num + 1;
    num2 = 123;
    num1 = 100;

    if(num2 > 1000)
    {
        return(1);  // endcheck
    }
    else(num2 > num1)
    {
        Resetincrement();   
        return(0);  // continue check by batch
    }
}
```

I keep getting error message on the else bracket. It says No Semicolon found but the sem colons are there. Not sure why. Maybe someone can see my mistake here?

Comment: it's not an answer to your question but a suggestion. It is better to have a single point exit. store the return value in a flag and return than in the end.

Comment: May I know what should I do to this question to gain back my posting privilege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this statement

```
else(num2 > num1)
```

to

```
else if (num2 > num1)
```

Also it is a bad idea to use global variables.

Take into account that the condition in the if statement

```
if(num2 > 1000)
```

will be always false because num2 is assigned 123

```
num2 = 123;
```

So the function has no any sense.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot provide a second conditional with `else` itself, use:

```
else if (num2 > num1)
```

Comment: and after you do that, provide a return at the end of the function, otherwise you get something like "not all code paths return a value"

Answer (score -1):

You should declare these variables: `num`, `num1`, and `num2`.

Then replace `else` with `else if`.

Comment: Your answer is a question